# Center table not to center of page

Tags: tables, align

Is it possible to place the center of table to 0.75 widthtext? I would like to center the table not to the center of page width but with respect to the 3/4 of page width.

```
\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
\caption[]{cap}\label{l}
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
a&b&c&d\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
a&b&c&d\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Center the `tabular` environment in a `minipage` of width `0.75\textwidth`?

Comment: What is your intention with the flushleft-environment?

Comment: BTW, there are lots of ways to center stuff (boxes), such as `\centering` and `\makebox[<width>][c]{...}`.  Note that some are implemented using trivlist and add extra space before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center the tabular environment like any other text using the center-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.75\linewidth}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lccc}
      \hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      a&b&c&d\\
      \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      a&b&c&d\\
      \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Note: the `\noindent` in front of `\begin{minipage}` is only needed, when the minipage appears as is after a text paragraph.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @LukášAltman - This solution is not correct, as it doesn't provide a `\noindent` directive before `\begin{minipage}`.

Comment: @Mico since we are right behind `\begin{document}` it is unnecessary, as would it be if the whole construct is within the `table` environment… But i edited my example accordingly, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the natural width of the `tabular` environment is less than `0.75\textwidth`, you may achieve your formatting objective by centering the `tabular` environment in a `minipage` of width `\0.75\textwidth`- .

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % show framelnes around text block
\usepackage{tabularx}  % for tabularx environment 
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}}
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tabularx}{0.25\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
abcdefhij\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{0.25\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
abcdefhij\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tabularx}{0.25\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
abcdefhij\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tabularx}{0.25\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
abcdefhij\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tabularx}{0.25\textwidth}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
abcdefhij\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you and in case of `flushleft` please? I added this case to my question. It is not in center of half page after compilation

Comment: @LukášAltman - Have you tried inserting a `\centering` directive after `\begin{flushleft}`?